# How can I send object by Node.js to browser in Real Time

Tags: javascript, node.js, asterisk

I am working on a project in Node.js and Asterisk AMI

Asterisk sends events to Node.js server and Node.js sends events in Obj to browser

My problem is the node server does not send a new object when updating data from AMI

```
var AsteriskAmi = require('asterisk-ami');
var ami = new AsteriskAmi( { host: '127.0.0.1', username: 'admin', password: '123456' } );
var Send;

ami.on('ami_data', function(data){

    // this obj update when ami send event
    Send = data;
});

ami.connect(function(){
});

var http = require('http');

var app = http.createServer(function(req,res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type': 'text/plain');

    //my problem here , object was sent but not update when ami send other object
    res.end(Send);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: `'text/plant'` is not a proper content type, second thing, you have also variable names mismatch declaring `var Send` but using `send` - it not necessary is the same. At last, you are not sending new events from `.on('ami_data')` - what should you do. Please perfect your code to let me answer after some offline test - i have done this once.

Comment: Building off of what @yergo, you also aren't doing it asynchronously which is what node.js is all about. It isn't guaranteed the variable `send` will receive the data by the time your `http.createServer`. You might need to send the request within the callback of `ami.on('ami_data')`

Comment: @yergo thank you but my problem not in syntax it's how to send obj after update in .on('ami_data) to res.end(Send)

Comment: @aug how I do that ? send data when ami.on('ami_data') update send value ?

Answer (score 2):

## 1. res.end(Send)

This is your first issue. When somebody is visiting your host, you are sending hat was collected as last message and you are sending it to browser. And closing connection. For real time event transportation to browser you should use `socket` based mechanisms like `socket.io`.

To connect to this server you will have to use an html page.

## Full working version in my environment - using `asterisk-manager`

In `public_html/test/index.html`:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <pre id="console">

    </pre>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.1.js"></script>
        <script>
            var __url = 'http://localhost';
            var __port = 3001;

            __socketurl = __url + ':' + __port;

            socket = io.connect(__socketurl);
            socket.on('notification', function (data) {
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data) + "\r\n";
            });
            socket.on('ami_event', function (data) {
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += JSON.stringify(data) + "\r\n";
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Above code tries to connect to server at `localhost:3001` and prints out every event coming from node app.

In `public_html/test/node/app.js`:

```
var app = require('http').createServer().listen(3001);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

var AsteriskAmi = require('asterisk-manager');
var ami = new require('asterisk-manager')('25038','192.168.0.2','amilogin','amipassword', true);


io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('notification', {message: "connected"});
});

ami.on('managerevent', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    io.sockets.emit('ami_event', data);
});

ami.connect(function(){
});
```

Above code opens a socket at port 3001 and keeps it until user diconnects.  Please refer to manual how to create IO servers [here](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/). Demo tutorias are available there also. Script does also connect to AMI itself and passes every event from AMI to every socket connected via `socket.io`.

Packages in `public_html/test/node/packages.json`:

```
{
    "name": "Server",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "socket.io": "latest",
        "asterisk-manager": "latest"
    }
}
```

Filled proper data in `app.js` to log into AMI, `npm install`'ed, `node app.js` and got it working flawlessly.

Comment: @yerog data from ami not send to browser ! I do  it  like you say

Comment: @Learnsilently i have providen you with fully working solution in my environment. If that does not work, I don't know whats your issue. Dont forget to edit AMI access data in `app.js` ;)